# Coin change, dynamic programming, but coin value reduces after first use

Tags: algorithm, dynamic-programming, knapsack-problem, coin-change

There are a lot of coin change questions and answers around but I couldn't find this one, and am wondering if it's even a coin change problem.

Basically I have a bunch of different coins, and an infinite amount of each coin.

So say there are stacks of various denominations. Each stack is infinite. (So infinite number of 25c coins, infinite number of 2c coins etc).

However, on top of each stack of coins is a special coin which has a value greater than (or equal) to the coins below. I can't access the coins below without using this coin on top.

What I'm trying to work out is the minimum number of coins required to make a certain sum.

I think this is solvable dynamic programming but I'm unsure how to add this limitation to the traditional solutions.

I was wondering if I should just remove the special coin in my list once I use it and replace it with the normal coins, but I can't seem to reason if that would break the algorithm or not.

Comment: It's basically the coin change DP. You should work one coin stack at a time, with a slightly more complicated DP update.

Comment: A the moment I'm thinking of calculating the minimum coins for each value from 0 up to the sum (like the traditional solution). To do this I check each stack, by iterating over a list of stacks L. If I find that the sum of sums is completed using a stack's special coin. I'll replace that special coin with the regular coin (in the list L), and it'll stay like that forever.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like a classic dynamic programming problem, where the challenge is to choose state correctly.

Usually, we choose sum of selected coins as problem state, and number of selected coins as state value. Transitions are every possible coin we can take. If we have 25c and 5c coins, we can move from state Sum with value Count to states `Sum+25,count+1` and `Sum+5,count+1`.

For your limitation, state should be augmented with information about which special(top) coins were taken. So you add a bit for each stack of coins. Then you just need to define possible transitions from every state. It is simple: if a bit for stack is set, it means that top coin was already taken and you can add a non-top coin from that stack to state sum, keeping all bits the same. Otherwise, you can take the top coin from that stack, ad its value to state sum, and set related bit.

You start from state with sum 0, all bits clear and value 0, then build states from the lowest sum up to target.

At the end, you should iterate over all possible combinations of bits and. compare values for state with the target sum and that bits combination. Choose the minimum - that would be the answer.

Example solution code:

```
#Available coins: (top coin value, other coins value)
stacks = [(17,8),(5,3),(11,1),(6,4)]
#Target sum
target_value = 70

states = dict()
states[(0,0)] = (0,None,None)
#DP going from sum 0 to target sum, bottom up:
for value in xrange(0, target_value):
    #For each sum, consider every possible combination of bits
    for bits in xrange(0, 2 ** len(stacks)):
        #Can we get to this sum with this bits?
        if (value,bits) in states:
            count = states[(value,bits)][0]
            #Let's take coin from each stack
            for stack in xrange(0, len(stacks)):                
                stack_bit = (1 << stack)                
                if bits & stack_bit:
                    #Top coin already used, take second
                    cost = stacks[stack][1]
                    transition = (value + cost, bits)
                else:
                    #Top coin not yet used
                    cost = stacks[stack][0]
                    transition = (value + cost, bits | stack_bit)
                #If we can get a better solution for state with sum and bits
                #update it 
                if (not (transition in states)) or states[transition][0] > count + 1:
                    #First element is coins number
                    #Second is 'backtrack reference'
                    #Third is coin value for this step
                    states[transition] = (count+1, (value,bits), cost)

min_count = target_value + 1
min_state = None
#Find the best solution over all states with sum=target_value
for bits in xrange(0, 2 ** len(stacks)):
    if (target_value,bits) in states:
        count = states[(target_value,bits)][0]
        if count < min_count:
            min_count = count
            min_state = (target_value, bits)
collected_coins = []
state = min_state
if state == None:
    print "No solution"
else:
    #Follow backtrack references to get individual coins
    while state <> (0,0):
        collected_coins.append(states[state][2])
        state = states[state][1]
    print "Solution: %s" % list(reversed(collected_coins))
```

Comment: Sorry, I thought I understood but actually I didn't. I don't quite understand your last paragraph, is it possible to expand on what happens between the second last and last paragraph?

For example, trying to find sum 10 with this stack:
6(5) 3(2)
At the moment my issue is I took a coin (6) to make sum 6 and marked that stack taken (stack became 5). At sum 10 two of those 5's were used. Sum 6 was not used as part of the solution. So I'm obviously am missing this iteration over all possible bits part?

Comment: Yes, thank you for the effort! That makes sense- having that extra requirements certainly adds more time complexity that I was thinking to start with.

Answer (score 0):

The below solution is based on two facts
1) Infinite number of coins in all available denominations

```
Algorithm:-

Let Given number be x

call the below method repeatedly until you reach your coin value, 
Each time of iteration pass the remaining value to be assigned with coins    and also the coin denomination

Method which will receive the number and the coin value
Parameters: x - coin to be allocated
            z - value of coin
if(x > z) {
   integer y = x/z * z
   if(y == x) {
      x is divisible by z and hence allocate with x/z number of coins of z value.
 }  
   if(Y != x) {
       x is not a multiple of z and hence allocate with x/z number of coins from z cents value and then for remaining amount repeat the same logic mentioned here by having the next greatest denomination of
  coin.

   }
 }
 else if(x < z) {
     return from this method;
 }
 else if(x == z) {
     x is divisible by z and hence allocate with x/z number of coins of z value    
 }


Example iteration:

Given number = 48c
Coins denomination: 25c, 10c, 5c, 2c, 1c

First Iteration:

Parameter x = 48c and z = 25c
return value would be a map of 1 coin of 25c, [25c , 1]
calculate the remaining amount 48c - 25c = 23c
23c is not equal to zero and not equal to 1 continue the loop.

Second Iteration:

Parameter x = 23c and z = 10c
return value would be a map of 2 coins of 10c, [10c, 2]
calculate the remaining amount 23c - 20c = 3c
3c is not equal to zero and not equal to 1 continue the loop.

Third Iteration:

Parameter x = 3c and z = 5c
No coins allocated
3c is not equal to zero and not equal to 1 continue the loop.

Fourth Iteration:

Parameter x = 3c and z = 2c
return value would be a map of 1 coin of 2c, [2c, 1]
Remaining amount 3c - 2c = 1c
Remaining amount Equals to 1 add an entry in map [1c, 1]


Final Map Entries:

[25c, 1]
[10c, 2]
[2c, 1]
[1c, 1]
[1c, 1]
```

Comment: Greedy algorithm doesn't work for this problem. Counterexample is x=29, coins={20, 14, 1}. Optimum is 3=2*14,1*1. Greedy solution is 10=1*20,9*1